# Ubuntu 15.04 installation stops at third step

Tags: system-installation, 15.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 15.04 AMD 64-Bit edition to my computer with Nvidia Geoforce 7025 graphics driver. I previously successfully installed it with `nomodeset` option during installation to my SATA disk. The drive failed and I bought a new SATA SSHD drive. Now, when I am trying to install ubuntu, the installation stops at the third step " Preparing to install ubuntu". The hard disk light blinks intermittently and the partition window does not appear.I have another PATA HDD of 80 GB capacity.

However, I can reach Live desktop from the installation DVD and can install Linux Mint 17.2 64-Bit Cinnamon well.But the latter has mounting problem, so I want to get Ubuntu.

What is going wrong and how to install ubuntu?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Tapas